# Radio Button Selector CSS ONLY pls

Tags: css, radio-button, css-selectors, label, checked

I have created a css image slider with radio buttons to control it. I have set the radio buttons to `visibility: hidden` and am using thumbnail images for the labels. The html looks something like this :

```
<div class="slider">
<input type="radio" value="navy" id="colour" name="attribute_colour" >
<label for="navy">
<img src="uploads/navy.png">
</label>
```

repeat lines 2-5 for other thumbnails, then :

```
<div class="slidermain"><ul>
<li>
<img src="uploads/navyfullsize.png">
</li>
```

repeat lines 2-4 for main images and close with :

```
</ul></div></div>`
```

I want clicking the image for `navy.png` to move the `<ul>` containing `navyfullsize.png` down 100%, so I would have thought that to select the button/image for `navy.png`, you should write this into the stylesheet :

```
.slider input[type=radio]:checked + label[for=navy]~.slidermain>ul  
{ top:-100%; }
```

But to no avail! I've tried a number of similar alternatives, I don't know anything about jquery, so the css solution would be very helpful please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Positioning an element requires either *position: relative* or *position: absolute*
2) Using percentage values **requires** the parent container's height to be set (for one 200px)
3) The label *for* attribute references the input **id**, not the value

Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Points 1) & 2) are in working order (originally omitted for brevity) but point 3)! I have tried both `.insidecover input[type=radio]:checked + label[value=navy]~.insidecovermain>ul { top:-100%; }` and `.insidecover input[type=radio]:checked + label[value="navy"]~.insidecovermain>ul { top:-100%; }` what could I be missing?

Comment: Sorry that code was meant to read : `.slider input[type=radio]:checked + label[value=navy]~.slidermain>ul { top:-100%; }` and `.slider input[type=radio]:checked + label[value="navy"]~.slidermain>ul { top:-100%; }` what could I be missing?

Comment: Actually it is label[for="navy"], not _value_